Filter Knowledge Articles Einstein Recommendation
I have a custom picklist field Tag__c in the Knowledge Article that will tag if the KBA is Internal or External. I want Einstein Recommendation to only display the Internal KBAs in LEX component.
I created a search configuration in the Search Manager where a rule is in place, Tag__c equals 'Internal' then assigned this filter in the Search Manager Configuration of the Knowledge LWC.
What happens now is that I can only search Internal KBAs (which is good) but the Einstein Recommendation is still displaying both Internal and External KBAs. Is there a way to limit Einstein Recommendation to only display internal KBAs? Thank you.
